# For Loop Will Not Run in Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

In the following code the for loop doesn't run. The msgbox displaying i doesn't activate once. The Range does clear, so A10:A300 is cleared. But after that, during the loop, nothing happens.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("B7")) Is Nothing Then
    Target.Worksheet.Range("A10", "A300").Clear
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    j = 10
    For i = 4 To 10
        MsgBox i
        If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2) = Target Then
            Target.Worksheet.Cells(j, 1) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3)
            j = j + 1
            MsgBox (ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 4))
        End If
    Next i
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `Target.Worksheet.Range("A10", "A300").Clear` will triggering `Worksheet_Change` again. So you have a recursive endless loop. To avoid this put `Application.EnableEvents = False` as frist command in the `Worksheet_Change` before the `If Not...` and `Application.EnableEvents = True` at the end before `End Sub`.

Comment: it seems after the Clear command nothing else gets run :/

Comment: Yes that works thanks a lot! :D